# transparent shader going black

Tags: transparency

I've searched for solution all around the internet but nothing seems to help.
In my project some of the bubbles always render as black blob. I know its related to not enough rays exiting the object.
Problem may be within the shader as different one renders properly. Any ideas?

[image]

[edited - I added the meterial nodes screenshots and a blend file]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to say, without your file ...

Comment: what are the 3 images? are you sure that it's not because of the world color or hdri?

Comment: Here it is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10NWElFmZms

Comment: @vklidu how to ad a .blend file here?

Comment: @moonboots world color strenght is set to 0 no hdri here

Comment: @diniulian thanks but I already watched this and it didnt helped me

Comment: @REFLEX Share file via https://blend-exchange.com copy given code and place into your Q (via Edit).

Comment: @vklidu done, if your willing to take a look at it and share your insights I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Partly it could be an issue of intersecting spheres. Partly I don't know ... So here is just some trick used to avoid glass darkening by affecting transparency by Ray Dept light path ...
Your shader ...

[image]

The trick addition ... from [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/glass-shader-looking-way-too-dark/1317449/11) ... just be sure Render Properties > Light Path > Transmission and Transparency is set like 12 ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried this technique also mentioned above in youtube video but somehow I was doing this wrong the whole time. case closed, thanks to everyone :)